# Migrating Codeplex SVN to Git with git svn clone

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, codeplex, migrating

In the past (2013), I was able to migrate a repository from Codeplex (under SVNBridge) to a Git repository.

I'm trying to do this again, with the same repository, and the 'git svn clone' method is not working.

Basically, it creates the .git folder and it's all. No code is downloaded, no message is issued...

I'm trying to execute this line of command:

> git svn clone https://mohid.svn.codeplex.com/svn -s mohid_code

As I said, no code is downloaded, but no messages are issued.

Am I missing something? 
Have someone tried to do this operation recently?

I noticed that Codeplex, for our project have been a little "unresponsive" in the last couple of days.

Any other ideas to get all the history and put on a git repository?
I've being trying to avoid using svn2git, but maybe I'll give it a try.

Thanks!
Eduardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
git svn clone https://mohid.svn.codeplex.com/svn mohid_code
```

without argument -s, because mohid doesn't use standard layout.

Also wait some time. First ~10 minutes looks like nothing hapens, because git try fetch revisions from 1 and first revision in mohid repo is 28559

Comment: Hello Sergey. I didn't realize that the repository was not standard. After the correction you suggested, the cloning worked! :). I avoided the wasted time using the -r 28559:HEAD option. Thanks!